# How to access files saved to my google drive api project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I create a google cloud platform Project. I set up a service using the google drive api. I can't figure out how to access the files that are being saved to the google drive.

Answer (score 0):

First you ahve to [enable Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-drive-api) and then you can have a look at [what you can actually do with it](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk).

You [can upload, list, deletete, update or search](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference?apix=true#Files) for the files. Pretty much full control.

Have a look at the "[resource representation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource-representations)" documentation with listed all the fields sescribing a file and methods for manipulating them.

Let's say you just want to list all the files in your Google Drive - on [this page you can try the Google Drive API list method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list).

Here are [all the drives' API methods](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) with the links to "try the API" pages.